# "plugin verification data mismatch" while loading plugin for qt5 project

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qt5

I have raw (no QtDesigner) Qt5 project with two simple plugins, which one don't load with laconic error: "plugin verification data mismatch".

Header of first plugin (which loads and run well):

```
#ifndef __PIROGRONIAN__P2P2__GUI_PLUGIN__H__
#define __PIROGRONIAN__P2P2__GUI_PLUGIN__H__

#include "QtCore/QtCore"
#include "PluginInterface.h"

namespace P2P2 {

    class GuiPlugin : public QObject, public PluginInterface {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "Pirogronian.P2P2.GuiPlugin")
        Q_INTERFACES(P2P2::PluginInterface)

    public:
        bool init(CoreServer *);
        bool receiveObject(Object*);
        int channelType();
    };
};

#endif
```

The second one, which don't load:

```
#ifndef __PIROGRONIAN__P2P2__CHAT_PLUGIN__H__
#define __PIROGRONIAN__P2P2__CHAT_PLUGIN__H__

#include <QtNetwork/QtNetwork>
#include "Chat.h"
#include "PluginInterface.h"

namespace P2P2 {

    class ChatPlugin : public QObject, public PluginInterface {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "Pirogronian.P2P2.ChatPlugin")
        Q_INTERFACES(P2P2::PluginInterface)

        CoreServer *_server;
        QHash<Channel *, Chat *> _chats;

    public:
        virtual bool init(CoreServer *);
        virtual bool receiveObject(Object *);
        virtual int channelType();
    };

};

//Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QPointer<P2P2::ChatPlugin>)

#endif
```

Here is PluginInterface header:

```
#ifndef __PIROGRONIAN__P2P2__PLUGIN_INTERFACE__H__
#define __PIROGRONIAN__P2P2__PLUGIN_INTERFACE__H__

#include "CoreServer.h"

namespace P2P2 {

    class PluginInterface {
    public:
        virtual bool init(CoreServer *) = 0;
        virtual bool receiveObject(Object *) = 0;
        virtual int channelType() = 0;
    };

};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(P2P2::PluginInterface, "Pirogronian/P2P2/PluginInterface/1.0")

#endif
```

I'm not expert and writing plugins for qt5 is described very cursorily. But since I can't find any major difference between those plugins, problem becomes rather mysterious to me. Mayby a bug in Qt? I've rebuilt both several times to bye sure that both are up to date.

I'm trying put the whole code somewhere into net, but it'll take a while... Edit: done - packed as zip here: http://uploaduj.net/D74c2f/v0-1-pure-zip/

Comment: set environment variable QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS to non zero.. rerun your program, post error message here.

Comment: Already done, but there is no messages about what is wrong with second plugin, just about loaded ones.

Comment: You mean the second plugin is not even mentioned in the output? This is not possible. Successfully loaded plugins are logged to console when this variable is set, and even more so failed load attempts. If there is nothing, your plugin is not found.

Comment: But here you are: [http://justpaste.it/l0vy . The plugin name is libChatPlugin.so, the almost last one. As you can see, nothing more about it... :(

Comment: Btw... one thing I never tried when I wrote plugins: Using one and the same interface for more than one plugin.

Comment: Except for ads and junk I don't see anything on this site. justpaste.it blocked as worthless.

Comment: Most of the time when a I created plugins and they did not load, it was missing dependencies. Undefined references due to missing files in .pro or CMakeLists.txt. But yes... ugly to debug.

Comment: I temporarily swap load commands, so this isn't problem with multiple plugins of the same interface, I think. And I tried another copy-pase service for plugins debug output: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1YKD

Comment: **Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE( ClassName, Identifier): This macro associates the given Identifier (a string literal) to the interface class called ClassName. The Identifier must be unique.** No sure if using the same interface for two plugins counts as 'unique'. But: Pure speculation.

Comment: Much better this paste-service :-) Could you try if chat is loading, if you remove the gui plugin?

Comment: After disabling loading the first plugin - still the same. So error is rather unrealted to first plugin.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77397/plugin-verification-data-mismatch-while-loading-plugin-for-qt5-project  <--- before the mods remind us that comments are no chat room ;-)

Comment: Very readily, but... " You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."

Comment: Hmm, thought this restricts only the creation of a room.

Comment: Write something, mayby I'll be able to reply. Edit: No, this dont work too :/

Comment: Stupid restriction. :-/

Comment: Cannot even give you explicitly write access....

Comment: Any override? Skype? Facebook? Gadu-Gadu (Polish one)? :-) My skype, if you wish: "pirogronian1"

Comment: I experimented a bit. In one of my projects I prevented the creation of one moc file. The plugin still compiled and linked, but when I tried to load it, I got exactly the same error message.... ok, NOT in Polish. :-)

Comment: So most likely you have somewhere an undefined reference. Maybe your plugin includes a class  from your main program, but does not include this file in your .pro file? Happened to me once, when I 'reused' an error handling class in my plugin. Took me some time to find this problem. When I added the error class to my .pro everything worked as expected.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ne230J3G

Comment: Well, to all who find this question and conversation... The (temporary) sollution was to add "qt" to CONFIG in .pro file, or (better, due to lack of warning about deprecated option) - erasing CONFIG line at all.

Comment: If you are still here... I have something for you :-)

Comment: For me `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(P2P2::PluginInterface, "Pirogronian/P2P2/PluginInterface/1.0")` looked strange with the slashes. When I changed my own plugins to this syntax, the plugins also don't load. I use dots, as mentioned in the docs [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtplugin.html#Q_PLUGIN_METADATA) and then it works:  `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(P2P2::PluginInterface, "Pirogronian.P2P2.PluginInterface.1.0")`

Comment: In guiplugin.pro you use `CONFIG         += plugin`, but in chatplugin.pro you use just `CONFIG = plugin` which sounds wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps but it seems that your plugin has invalid metadata. Here's code that sets error message http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/plugin/qlibrary.cpp#n303

You could use debug version of Qt and set breakpoint in that function. This would give you exact line that fails while loading your plugin.

Maybe you have an error in your metadata?

Comment: Invalid commit reference. Outdated link?